# Adding ACF to Woocommerce ul.products on Shop Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I'm using WooCommerce and Advanced Custom Fields, where ACF group is set up with post type for products. I would like to add a couple of simple text fields to the products box below the product title, and it will display on all products.

I have looked and found the hook for this to be `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title`

Image attached for visual description.

[image]

Like this I'm looking to add Address value (`$location`), Bedrooms value (`$bed`) and Bathrooms (`$bath`).

Please understand I am very new to PHP and still learning. I have tried to make an attempt, however I am unsure how to extract the field data from the product's post.

Any tips in the right direction to learn would really be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woo_products_property', 1 );
function woo_products_property() { 
    ?>          

<div class="property_loop_bottom_sec">
    <?php $location = get_field_object('address'); ?>
    <?php if( ! empty( $location ) ) { ?>
    <div class="feature">
    <div class="value"><i class="et-pb-icon map-marker">&#xe081;</i><?php echo $location['value'];?></div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    
    <?php $bed = get_field_object('bedroom'); ?>
    <?php if( ! empty( $bed ) ) { ?>
    <div class="feature">
    <div class="value"><i class="fas fa-bed"></i><?php echo $bed['value'];?></div>
    <span>Bed</span>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    
    <?php $bath = get_field_object('bathroom'); ?>
    <?php if( ! empty( $bath ) ) { ?>
    <div class="feature">
    <div class="value"><i class="fas fa-bath"></i><?php echo $bath['value'];?></div>
    <span>Bath</span>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

    <?php 
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revised your code. Try the below code.

```
function woo_products_property() {  
    global $post;
    ?>
    <div class="property_loop_bottom_sec">
        <?php 
        $location = get_field( 'address', $post->ID ); 
        if( ! empty( $location ) ) { ?>
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="value"><i class="et-pb-icon map-marker">&#xe081;</i><?php echo $location['value'];?></div>
            </div>
        <?php } 

        $bed = get_field( 'bedroom', $post->ID ); 
        if( ! empty( $bed ) ) { ?>
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="value"><i class="fas fa-bed"></i><?php echo $bed['value'];?></div>
                <span>Bed</span>
            </div>
        <?php } 

        $bath = get_field( 'bathroom', $post->ID); 
        if( ! empty( $bath ) ) { ?>
            <div class="feature">
                <div class="value"><i class="fas fa-bath"></i><?php echo $bath['value'];?></div>
                <span>Bath</span>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>

<?php } 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woo_products_property', 1 );
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Bhautik. The location field isn't playing well for me. Somehow it's working but only showing 1 Character. The Icon and Value is letter B. Whereas actual Value is 'Belmont Gardens, Town, Post Code' -> <div class="feature"><div class="value"><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>B</div></div>

Comment: Try to print `$location`

Comment: Hey Bhautik. Changed it to print $location but unfortunately seems to appear the same. Value for ACF $location is displaying first character only.

Comment: I think you miss understood when I said `print` `$location` variable to see what you got in that. like this `echo "<pre>"; print_r($location); echo "</pre>";` or `var_dump($location)`